# JS: making many simple calculators, dynamically or quickly?

Tags: javascript, html, user-input

For various electronics projects, I tend to make good use of cells in spreadsheets for calculating simple formulas (i.e. x = y^2 + j), however would love to have it across computers within a web page on a server.

How would I be able to make this, elegantly?

All I can think about is something like:

```
<input type="input" name="calculator_1_input_1" ......> /*rinse and repeat*/
```

However that tends to get very messy, long, convoluted and ugly.

Are there any ways you can think of, for example, where I can define something like "has 2 inputs, 1 output, formula is input 1 * input 2 + someconstant"? Maybe classes can be created that form new boxes and can just self-refer to "input 1" ?

Comment: out.value=in1.value*in2.value; where out, in1, and in2 are <input> IDs

Comment: Use a Google Docs spreadsheet.

Comment: @Matt I like the idea, but I may wish to integrate things in to the calculator down the road that are provided by PHP/HTML in the future, such as graphs or other interactions.

Comment: @dandavis, so I must have in_1_1 and in_2_1, and in_3_1 etc. when I have a vast number of calculators on the page? That is what I was hoping to avoid (and was in my example to if what I had wanted to avoid)

Comment: you should only need as many inputs as you have slots on the most input-needing calc; you can re-use them for different type of calculations, unless you need to be able to use more than one at once...

Comment: @dandavis I was thinking more like 15 separate lines of simple calculators, each with their own ability to calculate independently, rather than just having one.